# Trying to understand a function to swap two int values

Tags: c, pointers, swap

I know this function swaps two int values, but I'm trying to understand it 
minutely what is ***x=*y** exactly doing.

```
 1 void swap (int* x, int* y){
 2    int temp = *x; 
 3    *x = *y;
 4    *y = temp;
 5 }
 6
 7 int x,y;
 8 x = 1;
 9 y = 2;
10 swap(&x,&y)
```

The function receives two addresses, where  **x** and **y** lives, correspondingly.

An int variable, **temp**, is created and is assigned the value **1** from a dereferenced pointer to x.

The value **1** from a dereferenced pointer to **x** is assigned the value **2** from a dereferenced pointer to **y**. So, by ***x = *y**, I'm reading **1=2**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `shouldn't it just be x=*y?` ?? why dereferencing the first part and not the other part??

Comment: 'By *x = *y, I think the first * is not dereferencing x' well, you might think that..  'x=*y' would write the parameter 'x' which, as a parameter, would not affect the caller data in any way, since C passes by value, ie copies the argument into the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but otherwise, if both values are being dereferenced I'm  reading 1=2, which doesn't make sense at all to me...

Comment: @iLuAnzu the '=' is the C assignment operator.

Comment: I fully understand now. I apologize, I mixed other concepts with C language...

Comment: Do you understand this code: `int i = 1; int j = 2; i = j;`  ? Would you say that is doing `1 = 2` ?

Comment: @M.M No, i=j is updating the value of I. I missunderstood what *x was doing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to explain `*x = *y;` without using the word "dereference":

- `*x` represents the integer object pointed to by x. As it is the left operand of the assignment, it means that this integer object is going to be updated.
- `*y` represents the integer object pointed to by y. As it is the right operand of the assignment, it means that the content of the integer object (i.e. its value) is going to be used.
- `*x=*y` updates the integer object pointed to by x with the integer object pointed to by y.

**Note:** To clearly distinguish pointers from other types in the code, I suggest you to change naming as follows, using a prefix like `p_` for pointer variables for example:

```
 1 void swap (int* p_x, int* p_y){
 2    int temp = *p_x; 
 3    *p_x = *p_y;
 4    *p_y = temp;
 5 }
 6
 7 int x,y;
 8 x = 1;
 9 y = 2;
10 swap(&x,&y)
```

Comment: I'd rather use "the integer *object*"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I changed my formulation, but I prefer not using the word "object".

Comment: That's the problem. The C standard uses the word *object*. `3` is an integer and so is `5`. Pointers do not point to values but objects.

Comment: Right, I changed to use 'the integer object".

Answer (score 0):

When you assign something like `int abc = 5; int *ptr = &abc;` understand that :

- `ptr` is an integer pointer
- `&abc` is the address of the variable `abc`
- `ptr` stores addresss of the variable `abc`
- Writing `*ptr` is the equivalent to writing `abc`, and not same as writing `5` (a constant), although all three evaluates to `5` in an expression.

The `*` operator dereferences to give you the the variable , whose address is pointed to by `ptr` (i.e `abc`). Therefore it can be used as an lvalue(on the left side of an assignment).

Now in your example, when you tried the assignment `x = *y` you are trying to store the value pointed to by `y` ( which is an integer value) to `x` (which expects an address).

Now assume you somehow made the assignment, let us also assume that `&y`(i.e address of y ) is something like `1056`(only for example sake) and value pointed to by `y` is something like `5`. Then from now on `x` points to the address location `5` (which is not the actual address), thereby resulting in some garbage value.

Now an assignment like `x = y` would work flawlessly. But that would make the pointers `x` point to same location as pointed by `y` swap their pointing. That is if initially if `x` was pointing to variable `a` which was at address `1000` and `y` was pointing to a variable `b` which was at address `2000` , after the assignment valu of both `x` and `y` would be `1000`. It only means that now we have two pointers to the variable `b` at address `2000`, but has no impact on the actual variables. 
Whereas writing `*x = *y` is equivalent to writing `a = b`

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here in `swap(&x, &y);` you are passing the addresses of variable x & y as arguments to the function `swap(int* x, int* y)`.
2. As parameters of swap function are int pointers, the addresses of x and y are now stored in another int pointer type variables `x` and `y`.

   NOTE:

   *x and y coincidently have the same name in both the functions but the `x` and `y` used in swap function are int pointers and the `x` and `y` used outside the swap function are `int` variables.*
3. > The value 1 from a dereferenced pointer to x is assigned the value 2 from a dereferenced pointer to y. So, by *x = *y, I'm reading 1=2

   `*x=*y` is actually using an assignment operator with a left to right associativity. assignment operator assigns the value of right operand to the left operand.*don't read it as 1=2, it will as it may prove to be problematic later.*
4. > I tried to make some assumptions. By *x = *y, I think *x is not dereferencing x, but is the adress of x, and this is getting assigned the value 2 of the dereferenced pointer to y.

   `*x=*y` here, `*x` is the value of x and not the address of x and as described in point 3, this statement will assign the value of `*y` i.e. 2 to `*x`.
5. > But why, instead of *x=*y, shouldn't it just be x=*y?

   it shouldn't because `x` is an `int` pointer and `*y` is an `int` variable.